# How to curl a protobuf type_url?

Tags: protocol-buffers, envoyproxy

The Envoy documentation gives a [configuration example](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/listener_filters/tls_inspector#example) that specifies a `type_url` of `type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.listeners.tls_inspector.v3.TlsInspector` for a particular configuration stanza.

According to the [protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Any.FIELDS.string.google.protobuf.Any.type_url), a HTTP GET against this URL should return a protocol message type or an error.

Running `curl https://type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.listeners.tls_inspector.v3.TlsInspector` returns a 404. Is there a way to curl this URL to see the type? Or is the 404 the error the docs were referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature would be interesting, but it seems to be something of a relic, at least for the public version of protobuf.

[src/google/protobuf/any.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/68cb69ea68822d96eee6d6104463edf85e70d689/src/google/protobuf/any.proto#L147-L149):

```
  // Note: this functionality is not currently available in the official
  // protobuf release, and it is not used for type URLs beginning with
  // type.googleapis.com.
```